# While using a switch case loop, can i use the for loop for iterating the cases?

Tags: php, switch-statement

In PHP, While using a switch case loop, can i use the for loop for iterating the cases? 
 for example

```
switch .....

foreach($xyz as $abc)

{
 CASE:$abc
}

default;
```

> **UPDATE**

I am fetching the value from DB, this value is name of table, by using "case" I want to execute a particular query according to the table name..

Is this possible?

Comment: yes but use if instead of case

Comment: @nik What r the people here doing with there experience? for making us checking it?

Comment: @Trilli didnt get u pls elaborate...

Comment: what do you expect your code to do?

Comment: @knitti chk updated question above

Comment: @parth Oops Sorry buddy, i just thought that the time u took to elaborate the question could take u to the solution.

Comment: @nik hmmm actually u were right... I could have done that, solution was not that tough but u see I cam to know how other coders analyze... u know learning from analysis, Desi hai dost hum to... aalsi ho gaye ha baithe baithe.. :) How is dehradun ?

Comment: @parth Yeah "Learning From Analysis" gr8! Dehradun rocking, wat about ur roking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to put the `switch` statement into the `foreach`?

```
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    switch ($table) {
        case 'table_one' :
            // do something here
            break;
        case 'table_two' :
            // do something here
            break;
        case 'table_three' :
            // do something here
            break;
        default :
            // do some error handling here
            break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, a switch isn't that easy to read, consider going away from a `switch` and using an array-powered `if`, especially if you could *dynamically* create what you want to do each `case`:

```
$tables = array('table_one', 'table_two', 'table_three');
if (in_array($table, $tables)) {
    // do something here
} else {
    // do some error handling here
}
```

That's a lot more readable, even if your array has a lot of elements.

Comment: He is asking if he can dynamically generate the CASE statements.

Comment: U got me right, thats what i want to do,this could be done but I have bunch of around 32 tables, they are all Joomla tables u see they have lots of tables, so the solution u have suggested could be very lenghty u see... any thing else u can suggest for this???

Comment: @Finbarr: Ooh, now I see it. Nope. But *usually* (probably not always), you can fix the underlying problem by changing the loops around. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Parth: Edited my answer, hopefully that helps. You could embed that in your `foreach` with `$table` as the variable you're pulling if that's still a necessary construct.

Comment: Hmmm True Very... I will do this.. Thanks Gothic... :) God Bless You

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you can dynamically generate CASE declarations in PHP switch statements in this way.

What you are talking about doing is getting all of your tables in an array, then looping through them inside a switch statement to automatically declare your CASE statements. You cannot do this.

It generates:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH, expecting T_CASE or T_DEFAULT`

Comment: pls elaborate what do mean by dynamically generation here in my question..may u are getting me wrong here..

Comment: +1 Thanks Mate I got your point.. actually i am new to programming terminology....

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  as per the OP's comments , i am writing this answer

```
   $query=null;
    switch($tableName):
    {
    case "table1":
    $query="...";
    break;
    case "table2":
    $query="...";
    break;
    case "table3":
    $query="...";
    break;
    }
    ....

here goes  logic to  execute that query
```

If you have too many tables then put those querys in array check like this ,

```
$arr = array("table1"=>"query1","table2"=>"query2","table3"=>"query3",....);
$query  = $arr[$tableName];
```

here goes the logic to execute query

Comment: @reddy Saahab This could be very lengthy in case of Joomla 32 table hote hai usme.. :) lamba ho jayegaa.. Koi aur idea do plsss